How can I detect row changes originating outside MUI Data Grid and trigger a function
I'm using MUI Data Grid to display a list of items (Purchase Orders). Each item can be edited or updated on the server (via React Query), which means the data can change outside the grid. I'm aware that MUI Data Grid does not provide a built-in mechanism to detect external changes to row data and automatically trigger a callback.

const CustomToolbar = ({ refetch }: GridToolbarProps) => {

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer className="flex flex-row-reverse justify-between w-full ">
      <Box component="div">
        <RefetchBtn refetch={refetch}/>
        <GridToolbarQuickFilter />
      
      </Box>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
};

const TablePurchaseOrders = (props: UseQueryResult<IPurchaseOrder[], Error> & { hideToolbar?: boolean }) => {
  const { data: pos, isLoading, isRefetching, isError, error, refetch, hideToolbar = false } = props;
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

  const rows = useMemo(
    () =>
      pos
        ?.filter(pd => {
          return pd.active === active;
        })
        .map(pd => {
          return { ...pd, id: pd._id };
        }) || [],
    [pos, statusFilter, active],
  );


  return (
    <DataGrid
      slots={{
        toolbar: !hideToolbar ? CustomToolbar : null,
      }}
      slotProps={{
        toolbar: {
          refetch: refetch,
        },
      }}
      loading={isLoading || isRefetching}
      hideFooter
      disableRowSelectionOnClick
      rows={rows}
      columns={columnsPurchaseOrders}
    />
  );
};

export default TablePurchaseOrders;


Scenario:

I fetch a list of items from the server (React Query) and pass them to the Data Grid via the rows prop.

I have a detail page for each item (fetched with a separate React Query key). When a user navigates to a detail page, that detail data is cached.

When I return to the grid and see that an item’s status has changed after a re-fetch, I want to invalidate the query for that item so that going back to the detail page will fetch the newest data instead of using the old cached data.


Goal:
I want to identify which rows have changed (for example, a status field update) after a re-fetch, and then call invalidateQueries(['po', changedPoId]) for each updated item.
